# Arranging <p> tag using css

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I am using Wordpress and ran into an issue where the captcha is being positioned below the login button and kind of out of sight.

This is my code I want to move the bottom p tag to the top using css.

```
<div>
    <p>login button</p>
    <p>forget password link</p>
    <p>register link</p>
    <p>captcha button<p>
</div>
```

Comment: 1) post your actual code (a fiddle is even better) 2) if you want to place a p over another, just move it in your html...

Comment: I wish I did but it's Wordpress so I don't.

Comment: wordpress or not, there must be some code to generate the HTML... change that code. changing positions with CSS in that case would be a very bad idea.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We probably need a lot more information about the layout to help out, but assuming you can't change the HTML at all, what you can do is make the container `<div>` `position: relative` and use `position: absolute; bottom: 100%` on the captcha element to have it appear at the top.

http://jsfiddle.net/L5vER/

Comment: Better than [my attempt](http://jsfiddle.net/Yff8M/), I was adding negative `margin-top` to the captcha and compensating for it with extra `padding`. _Mental note made_ :)